# Is there any section managing tool/ panel for indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, section-marker

In Indesign going through sections in multi documents or long documents to editing their titles and other options is a time eating process.
Is there a panel, script or plug-in to just list sections... *as documents as in a book*... and let designer to see them stacked and bring up the section option by just one click, instead scrolling all page panel up and down?

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, don't know any place that merely list sections.

However, you might find document navigation easier utilizing the little navigator in the lower left corner of the Document Window.

If you click the down arrow, you can see a list of pages, Sections can be easily "jumped" to by merely selecting the differing page numbers, assuming they vary.

[image]

If your page numbering doesn't reflect sections, this won't be of much use.

Realize that sections are merely where page numbering changes. So there would probably be little use for a "Sections Panel". What I do, when creating sections is to add a color label to the page thumbnail in the Page Panel. That way, in an instant, I can see where sections start.

Comment: Thanks for notifing me page viewer in below of screen, I'm using it much and it haves a lot usage in my work flow... but this process for section editing is as annoying as pages panel is. In long docs and too many sections we have a part-job just to do a lot renaming in sections. for example 20 sections per every 20 books. its just eats brains!!